# Is there way to show list items (only 1 column choice field) on a modern page?

Tags: list-view, dropdown

Is there a way to display all the items from a list. Only 1 choice column "Category" need to be displayed. So it has to be dropdown. I had it in the classic page (html, jquery with css).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern SharePoint pages JavaScript injecting is sunset by Microsoft.

For custom web part in modern pages you must have to use SPFx solution.

Refer this Microsoft docs for SPFx webpart

[Build SPFx web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)